# how to know that string contain some characters?

Tags: c#, string, path, split

hello i want to do wit this string,

```
D:\Bank Pelapor\BNI\Repository\201209\Instance\123456789-2012-09-30-BSMS1-1.xbrl
```

the path is consist with the file with versioning , which is -1 before the file extension, i want to do something,

right now i already do with this code, I Split the path  :

```
string[] filefile = dr["Path_XBRL"].ToString().Split('\\', '-');


   if( filefile.length >11)
    {

      do.something();

    }

    else
    {
      do.somethingelse();
    }
```

but i'm afraid that someday the path is changing or revised, is there any solutions?

Comment: so thats the versioning of file on a path, i use - 1 in every new uploaded file with the same name, so when thats file with -1 i want to do something, and i get confused how to check the -1:p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `path` will have the following format : `"{DirectoryName}\{FileName}-{VersionNumber}.{Extension}"`.

To get the file name in a path without its extension : `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myPath)` in `System.IO`.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);  // Gets the file name without extension
string versionString = fileName.Split('-').LastOrDefault();  // Gets the string after the last "-"
int version;
if(int.TryParse(versionString, out version))  // If "versionString" can be converted into an integer
    // TODO : If there is a version number (stored in "version")
else
    // TODO : If there is no version number
```

Comment: i already us Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myPath) but, the filename and versioning is diffrent in every single record..

Comment: @SabilValdano In _System.Linq_ namespace.